# change values in groupby object with multi index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following df that I group and then try to change values of US with the overall per type sum, but I get nan:

```
dff=pd.DataFrame({'country':['US','US','UK','UK','FR','FR','ES','ES'],'type':['A','B','C','B','A','C','A','B'],'sales':[100,200,100,100,50,10,20,40]})

grouped=dff.groupby(['country','type'])['sales'].sum()

grouped['US']=dff.loc[dff.country!='US'].groupby('type')['sales'].sum()

print(grouped)
```

[image]

And I want to get:

```
US   A   70

US   B   140
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
dff.loc[dff.country != 'US'].groupby('type')['sales'].sum()
```

you get 3 values

```
type
A     70
B    140
C    110
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

But

```
grouped["US"]
```

has only 2 values

```
type
A     70
B    140
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

You can try it:

```
dff.loc[dff.country != 'US'].groupby('type')['sales'].sum()[["A", "B"]]
```

```
type
A     70
B    140
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) for assign Series to `US` level:

```
s = dff.loc[dff.country!='US'].groupby('type')['sales'].sum()
s.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['US'], s.index])
grouped['US'] = s

print (grouped)
country  type
ES       A        20
         B        40
FR       A        50
         C        10
UK       B       100
         C       100
US       A        70
         B       140
Name: sales, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pivot` to assign the values to `US` :

```
dff=pd.DataFrame({'country':['US','US','UK','UK','FR','FR','ES','ES'],'type':['A','B','C','B','A','C','A','B'],'sales':[100,200,100,100,50,10,20,40]})

#use as_index=False to keep group keys within the dataframe
grouped=dff.groupby(['country','type'],as_index=False)['sales'].sum()

grouped.loc[lambda x: x.country.eq("US"), "sales"] = (grouped
                                                       #filter out US
                                                       #and search for A and B in the type column
                                                      .query("country != 'US' and type in ['A','B']")
                                                      .pivot(columns='type',values='sales')
                                                      .sum()
                                                      .array)

grouped

    country type    sales
0     ES    A        20
1     ES    B        40
2     FR    A        50
3     FR    C        10
4     UK    B        100
5     UK    C        100
6     US    A        70
7     US    B        140
```